# Propositional Logic meta-variable notation abuse

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

When defining Formation Sequence, van Dalen (4th edition page 9) says:

> A sequence $(\varphi_0,\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n)$ is called a formation sequence of $\varphi$ if $\varphi_n=\varphi$ and:
>
> (i)$ \varphi_i $ is atomic;
>
> (ii)$\varphi_i = (\varphi_j \square \varphi_k) $ with $j,k<i \quad$ (where $\square \in \{\land, \lor, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow\})$
>
> (iii)$\varphi_i = (\neg \varphi_j) $ with $j<i$

But he then says:

> Observe that in this definition we are considering strings $\varphi$ of symbols from the given alphabet; this mildly abuses our notational convention

But the notation convention was to use $\varphi$ as meta-variable for propositions, and this is what my eyes see here.

Am I supposed to make a distinction between propositions and strings of propositional logic alphabet symbols? Aren´t propositions a subset of propositional alphabet strings?

Comment: not sure what you mean (where does the box stand for) also does (iii) really have brackets? (and there is no k in (iii)

Comment: to me it looks a bit like the list on how to decide if a formula is wellformed, only now upside down, so starting with atomic sentences make all possible formulas  hope this helps

Comment: sorry edited, the square was defined before. The brackets are necessary.

Comment: It does read rather chaotic if you follow it exactly as given $ \varphi \to \varphi $ can be part of the formation sequence of $ \varphi \lor \varphi $  maybe the author means something like "don't create subformulas of $ \varphi_n $ this way, it is only a theoretical way to create all possible formulas of the language"

Comment: The definition is permissive indeed, one (not the) formation sequence can contain "garbage".

Comment: sigh, editing again. Need to double-check before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is in the paragraph following **Definition 1.1.4** of *formation sequence*.

> *Examples*. (a) $⊥, p_2, p_3, (⊥ \lor p_2), (¬(⊥ \lor p_2)), (¬p_3)$ and $p_3, (¬p_3)$ are both formation sequences of $(¬p_3)$. Note that formation sequences *may contain ‘garbage’* [emphasis added].

As you noted [page 8] : "$\varphi$ and $\psi$ are used as variables for propositions".

In the example above of the *formation sequence*, the *meta-variables* $\varphi_i$ stand for  strings of symbols.

Comment: So the abuse is using $\varphi$ for expression variable instead of proposition variable? wow, this is what I call a *mild* abuse.

Comment: @Victor - yes; he "abuse" of $\varphi$, that has been introduced to refer to *propositions*, using it to refer also to strings of symbols which are not propositions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA why is $(\bot \lor p_2)$ not wellformed? (or is $\bot$ not wellformed anyway)